# Publishing to the chrome web store is not working

Tags: chrome-web-store

On Friday I published a chrome extension with restricted access to testers. Whenever I check the status of the chrome extension I am given an error message that says "Your item has been published to testers. All changes will take effect within a few minutes." It has obviously been days since I first tried to test the extension and I feel like I have tried just about everything to resolve this. Has anyone experienced something similar? If you have any guidance would be greatly appreciated.